# How to change style of a child angular component to be same size as another child component

Tags: html, css, angular

I have been struggling with this for a quite some time now, and i couldn't find a sufficient answer. Basically i have one parent component which html goes as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <child-one></child-one>
    <child-two></child-two>
</div>
```

the problem is that the child-one component has its size set as auto, with some padding to look good,

```
child-one {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

and child-two has a fixed width and height in it's own scss.

```
child-two {
    width: 10rem;
    height: auto;
 }
```

is there a way to somehow change the width of child-two in the parent without editing the child-two?

I was hoping for something along the lines of storing the width of the child-one, and setting the width of child-two to the same value.

```
child-one { 
    width:auto;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    $width: this.width !global //idk about this one
 }

child-two {
    width: $width
    padding: 0.5rem
 }
```

*please note that the child-one and child-two scss don't look this way in the code, and are normally written, this is just for the purpose of simplifying the question*

Comment: **YOUR QUESTION** Is there a way to somehow change the width of child-two in the parent without editing the child-two?   ***MY QUESTION***, do you want to change the width of child-two in the parent based on a condition?

Comment: well yes, i want to change the style of the child-two in the parent to be based on a condition, or a variable, that would be better

Comment: `@ViewChild` might help you ;)

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti's suggestion is a valid suggestion, alternatively, you could use **ngStyle** to provide dynamic styling for the component or **ngClass** for conditionally applying style class to the component. You could, which requires more code, also write a directive (using ElementRef) that changes the behaviour of the component based on certain conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

**app.component.html** - Parent Component

```
<child-one #childOne></child-one>
<child-two #childTwo></child-two>
<br>
<button (click)="changeWidth()">Change child two width</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('childOne', {
    read: ElementRef
  }) childOne: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('childTwo', {
    read: ElementRef
  }) childTwo: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  changeWidth() {
    const childOneWidth = this.childOne.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('child-one')[0].offsetWidth;
    const childTwoElement = this.childTwo.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('child-two')[0];
    this.renderer.setStyle(childTwoElement, 'width', `${childOneWidth - 2}px`);
  }
}
```

Here is the working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b3gruh)

Comment: it works indeed, and works well, but i was wondering if i could do this without using the getElementByClassname() method, but now i see why you can't really go around it...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I got in my mind. Will wait for other SO guys for their suggestions or new answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Suggestion

@SivakumarTadisetti's suggestion is a valid suggestion, alternatively, you could use `ngStyle` to provide dynamic styling for the component or `ngClass` for conditionally applying style class to the component. You could, *which requires more code*, also write a directive that changes the style behaviour of the component based on certain conditions.

### Example using ngStyle

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-help-01